# Open a different page for a download link

Tags: html, hyperlink

Hi I have a link on my portfolio website which downloads an .exe file so people can check out some of my work.

the link is something like this

```
<a href="downloads/project.exe">Download Here!</a>
```

The problem I have is that I want to open another link. So when the Person presses "Download here!" it will download the .exe and also open another html page I have.

ANy idea's on how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="javascript:openNew()">Link</a>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function openNew(){
        console.log("Lets Begin");
        window.open("http://www.facebook.com");
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
    }

</script>
```